# How to change where a computer is looking for fonts

Tags: java, fonts, redhat

I am having issues with fonts and different machines. I am running a java program on a red hat 6 computer. Currently, all of the available fonts are in a folder like user/share/fonts but I want to direct the computer to look for fonts in user/other/fonts.

Comment: Read Java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html

Comment: Since you tagged your question with `java` you should make clear whether you want to change where “the computer looks for fonts” or where the *JVM* looks for fonts.